# How I could modify webservice according to mysql modification

Tags: php, mysql, json

I wrote this code as a web service  that  it returned  json array  could be     by an android app .

How the app could parsed all data if there an addition in MySQL  database during  running the app.

```
<?php
ini_set('default_charset','UTF-8');
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "passw";
$dbname = "db";
$conn = mysql_connect($servername, $username, $password,$dbname);

    //fetch table rows from mysql db
    $sql = "select * from t_name where  id=1";
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT ID from db.t_name where  id =1" )           
     or die("Error in Selecting " . mysqli_error($connection));

    //create an array
    $emparray[] = array();
    while($row =mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $emparray[] = $row;
    }
    echo json_encode($emparray);

    //close the db connection
    mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: You're asking how you could ***push updates*** to your client app? That's a bit broad; what you have is not going to get you very far at all. Have you looked into this topic at all?

Comment: ***Push updates.*** A.k.a. push notifications.

Answer (score 0):

Android app will not get affected with additional columns added in yourable, but will defiantly get affected if you change the data type from int to var char or remove the column

The reason behind this is becasue the application will not be using your additional fields so it does not matters him if a few more columns are being added to it

it will only get affected if the columns it is using are not accessible either if you changed its datatype from int to some string or if they stop getting that particular field application will start getting error or crashes.

Comment: My question about how to push update to the android  through the web service?

Comment: You can not unless your android application understands it, look it is a 2 way communication with a predefined set of rules, you have to decide that if there is an update in a particular row using some flag, and android application would check that flag if it is set or not,

Comment: In my case I would have added a last modified time column in the table thus android application would verify the last modified time with the one it received in json from the one they have saved it in db or there keychain if they find that last modified time in json > last modified time in there db they will updated that record in there db otherwise skip that record